# In GNU/Linux, is there a preformace benefit of using pthread_cond_t instead of an array of semaphores?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, condition-variable

In the following scheme: awakening N control threads, then waiting for all of them to finish with that work, then repeating (finitely many times), is there a performance benefit (less time is spent on synchronizatoin) in using a single `pthread_cond_t` (with the corresponding mutex and plain variables to store whether the condition has happened) instead of 2 arrays of binary semaphores (2 per thread)?.

In the current solution, I'm using semaphores. To awake the threads from the control thread, I post to each thread corresponding “wake” semaphore. To synchronize the worker threads with the control thread, in the control thread I wait for each thread ”done” binary semaphore. The worker threads are themselves in as loop as well; for each iteration, they wait on the “wake-up” semaphore and post on the “done” semaphore.

I suppose that using an array of semaphores uses more memory. I can't benchmark a meaningful difference because my development environment supports 2 hardware threads, and the code is intended to run on environments with much more (64). Does `pthread_cond_t` has to do something similar that offsets the performance advantages of using a synchronization structure instead of an array of semaphores?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29) user case.

Comment: @qqibrow: A simple barrier doesn't work, since a part of code in the control thread has to execute after all workers have finished but before they resume.